# Did Abraham Lincoln have a duel with cannons?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, abraham-lincoln

When you where challenged to a duel or challenged someone to a duel, it was the person that was challenged that chose the weapon. Once someone challenged Lincoln To a duel and he said " how about cannons?". I can't find any historic evidence of this duel actually happening, so I wanted to know if he ever duelled someone with a cannon?

Comment: Questions with apocryphal or hypothetical/fanciful assumptions are off topic. If this is some real quote, you need to identify what is, otherwise I will assume you are just making it up and vote to close.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a fabricated premise or mis-statment of fact.

Comment: Or someone watching the Duel between the Duke of Wellington and Edmund Blackadder pretending to be the Prince of Wales...

Comment: @TylerDurden The question holds value if the apocrypha is common.

Comment: I don't know if the cannon idea is common...Google didn't pull up an assertion. But by de-emphasizing the cannon the question could be saved.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Abe Lincoln did fight a duel in 1842.  He was blamed by James Shields for an editorial. He chose extremely large broadswords, to improve his reach.  I have heard that he joked at the choice of weapons "How about cow dung at 50 paces?"  I personally haven't heard the cannon joke, but he might have used it as well.

> Since Lincoln was challenged by Shields he had the privilege of choosing the weapon of the duel.  He chose cavalry broadswords "of the largest size."  "I didn't want the d—-d fellow to kill me, which I think he would have done if we had selected pistols," he later explained.  For his own part, he did not want to kill Shields, but "felt sure [he] could disarm him" with a blade.   At six feet, four inches tall, Lincoln planned to use his height to his advantage against Shields, who stood at a mere five feet, nine inches tall.
>
> The day of the duel, September 22, arrived and the combatants met at Bloody Island, Missouri to face death or victory.  As the two men faced each other, with a plank between them that neither was allowed to cross, Lincoln swung his sword high above Shields to cut through a nearby tree branch.  This act demonstrated the immensity of Lincoln’s reach and strength and was enough to show Shields that he was at a fatal disadvantage.  With the encouragement of bystanders, the two men called a truce.

[Source](http://www.civilwar.org/education/history/lincoln-hub/abraham-lincolns-duel.html)

Comment: @Mike Does it matter? It doesn't change the content, meaning or relevance of the answer.